# How to prevent the ip address of an interface from disappearing when restarting the direct-connected interface

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip

NIC A and NIC B are direct-connected. I assign static IPv4 address to the interfaces. However, when I use

```shell
ip link set $IFACE down/up
```

to restart the interface B, the IP address of the interface A will disappear. How can I prevent the IP address of A from disappearing when restarting the interface B?

- assign static ip to A

  ```shellsession
  $ ip addr add 192.168.1.192/24 dev enp0
  $ ifconfig
  enp0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
          inet 192.168.1.192  netmask 255.255.255.0 ...
  ```
- then restart B

  ```shellsession
  $ ip link set enp1 down
  $ ip link set enp1 up
  ```
- The ipv4 address of A disappears

  ```shellsession
  $ ifconfig
  enp0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
          inet6 fe80::1ac0 ...
  ```

I'm running NetworkManger. However, after I executed `sudo nmcli dev set enp0 managed no`, the same phenomenon still occurs.

Comment: Are you running any connection manager, like NetworkManager or systemd-networkd? Those might deconfigure an interface on link loss, unless you tell them to keep their hands off statically-configured interfaces.

Comment: This is not done by the kernel (at least for IPv4, IPv6 can have a different default behavior). it's done by a network tool handling this interface. So an answer would depend on what additional information you'll put in the question about this.

Comment: Try it in a namespace (`ip netns add experiment` and then interactively: `ip netns exec experiment bash -l`  and as first command: `ip netns id` to confirm the shell is there) to at least be convinced it's because of your environment (after NetworkManager there can still be something else, eg systemd). The pair of connected interfaces can be simulated with `ip link add name enp0 up type veth peer name enp1; ip link set enp1 up`. Here no address loss. Once convinced, you'll know you have to put efforts in the question to describe your environment.

Comment: And to witness (on the host, not the experiment anymore) that the address is deleted, you can keep running  `ip monitor addr dev enp0` in a separate shell while doing down/up. But that won't tell what did it (and neither if it's expected behavior, even if I know it isn't).